# linux kernel `min` macros

Tags: c, macros

I was looking through linux kernel source code (`kernel.h`) and I found this macro for `min` function:

```
#ifndef max
#define max(x, y) ({                \
    typeof(x) _max1 = (x);          \
    typeof(y) _max2 = (y);          \
    (void) (&_max1 == &_max2);      \
    _max1 > _max2 ? _max1 : _max2; })
#endif
```

And now I'm wondering what does `(void) (&_max1 == &_max2);` line do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It prevents accidental type casting of `x` or `y`. You can arithmetical compare differently sized integers with the same sign, but you must not compare their pointers. I.e. this code would generate a compiler warning:

```
short a = 47;
long b = 11;
min(a, b);
```

C.f. [Is comparing two void pointers to different objects defined in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8225501/416224)