# pointer equality test with same address yields false

Tags: c++, qt, c++14, visual-studio-2019, void-pointers

Why is this pointer comparison not working?

```
// in handleSlot()...
void* ptr1 = m_expected; // defined as SimpleBase*
void* ptr2 = sender(); // defined as QObject*
if (ptr1 != ptr2)
    return; // this should not be reached, since the debugger shows ptr1 and ptr2 are the same
```

The background here is that I have a templated type which inherits from both `QObject` and `T`, where `T` is a subclass of `SimpleBase`. Since I don't know which template instantiation has triggered the slot, I can't do a dynamic cast here to directly compare pointers of the same type.

I also tried comparing the pointer addresses using `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>`, but when I did that oddly enough they yielded different integers.

I was able to workaround the problem by adding an argument to the signal and slot so that it passes `const SimpleBase *` i.e. `this`, and the pointer comparison works that way. But I am curious if there is a way to compare these pointers as they were, using `sender()` instead of passing the extra argument?

Comment: Please provide a full [MCVE] so we can run and reproduce your issue. For all we know, this may not actually be the problem code causing the behavior you think it is.

Comment: FWIW, the `QObject` part of the class and the `SimpleBase` part of the class will have different addresses, even if the point to the same object.

Comment: This is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42504012/8593689. In short, what @NathanOliver said is correct, the answer I linked goes into detail as to why this is.

Comment: It seems you can `dynamic_cast<SimpleType*>(sender())` or `dynamic_cast<QObject*>(m_expected)` assuming both are unique and have a `virtual` function. Multi-inherited bases do have different actual addresses and you can’t compare them fir equality using `void*` always.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - that's the answer. it did not occur to me that I could dynamic cast between two declared types that weren't directly related. but I guess the runtime information allows that to happen. feel free to write up as answer and I'll give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can `dynamic_cast<SimpleType*>(sender())` or `dynamic_cast<QObject*>(m_expected)` assuming both are unique and have a `virtual` function. Multi-inherited bases do have different actual addresses and you can’t compare them for equality using `void*` always.

Comment: Actually according to this other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/8225501/7098259 using void* to test for object identity is valid in C++, but must be casted via dynamic_cast