# Legal dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I would like to know how to solve this problem. I don’t understand what this question is asking me:

```
dynamic_cast<Y>(new X)
```

- To Be legal?
- To probably succeed?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: It is asking you which combinations of types for `Y` and `X` make this code legal and which combinations of types for `Y` and `X` make it likely to succeed. For example, if `Y` is a base class of `X` and has a virtual destructor, ...

Answer (score 3):

The question should be:

> What can you say about the definitions of `X` and `Y` so that the following code is legal, and furthermore that the cast succeeds?

Then the answer is fairly straight-forward: `X` has to be a complete type for the `new` expression to be legal. Dynamic casts are valid for upcasting to a non-virtual base, so if `Y` is a pointer to a non-virtual base (possibly CV-qualified, and including a pointer to `X` itself), the cast is valid *and* succeeds.

Moreover, there are other valid uses of dynamic casts on *polymorphic* types (i.e. classes with virtual functions). If `X` is polymorphic, then `Y` may be [`void *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123776/are-there-practical-uses-for-dynamic-casting-to-void-pointer), or `Y` may be a pointer to any other class in the inheritance hierarchy of `X`. However, the cast will only *succeed* if `Y` is a pointer to a base (however, this base may be virtual!).

(The reasoning for the present is simpler than for an arbitrary dynamic cast, since we already know the dynamic type of the castee. In general, dynamic casts can do far more complicated things.)

Comment: That's not true.  If `Y` is a pointer to a base class of `X`, then `X` doesn't have to be polymorphic.  And if `Y` is `void*`, the cast will succeed (but will only be legal if `X` is polymorphic).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Interesting. Let me double-check that. Good point about `void*`, I should really have thought of that.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks, you're right. Now the answer is getting very long. I wonder if I should just delete it. Let me see if I can make it correct without too many words.

Comment: @KerrekSB The real answer is fairly long.  C++ isn't a simple language.  (We've also not considered the role of cv_qualifiers; e.g. `Y` could be `X const*`, for example.  In this case, since the results of `new X` can't be cv qualified, I don't think they play a significant role, but if you want to be complete...)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Edited -- what do you think?

Comment: @KerrekSB And your answer is still incorrect.  _If_ `Y` is a pointer to `X`, or to a base class of `X`, then there is no requirement that `X` be polymorphic.  In such cases, `dynamic_cast` is just another spelling of `static_cast`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, very true... can dynamic casts cast away constness, or only add it? Again the present case is simple because we know the value of the castee, and "a pointer" subsumes "a cv-qualified pointer".

Comment: @JamesKanze: I consider `X` to be a base class of itself. Does that make sense? I think that's what `is_base_of` says, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB They can only increase cv-qualification (which also include `volatile`, in addition to `const`); they cannot reduce it.  But as I said, in this case, the results of `new X` have no cv-qualifications, so any cv-qualifiers in `Y` would only increase cv-qualification, and so be legal.

Comment: @KerrekSB I tend to agree with you that `X` is a base class of `X`.  I'm not sure that the standard agrees, or that it agrees everywhere, and I'm sure that a lot of readers wouldn't automatically consider it to be the case.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The standard says that `B` is a base of `const B`; see 20.9.6/3.

Comment: @KerrekSB And §10/2 says something different.  It's not the
first time the standard has been inconsistent in its
terminology.

Answer (score 3):

First, to be legal, `Y` must be a pointer type.  So let's
rewrite the question as `dynamic_cast<Y
cv_qualifiers*>( new X )`.  Having done this, it's
legal if `X` is a complete class type, and if either `X` is a
polymorphic type, or `Y` is the same type as `X` or is a base
class of `X`.

It will succeed if `Y` is the same as `X`, or is a base class of
`X`.  Note that in these cases, `dynamic_cast` has the same
behavior as `static_cast`, and in fact corresponds to an
implicit conversion, so one would normally just write `new X`,
without any cast.  (There are a few special cases where the cast
might be necessary, typically when passing the results to a `void*` parameter.  In such cases, I would prefer
`static_cast`, but the semantics of the two are exactly the
same in this case.)

Finally, there is one special case (which will also succeed): if
`X` is a polymorphic type, and `Y` is `void
cv_qualifiers *`.  In this case, the `dynamic_cast`
*does* have different semantics than `static_cast`, although
since the `X*` returned from `new X` will have the type
“pointer to most derived type”, the actual effect
will be identical (and again, the same as the implicit
conversion).

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point.  That would be another case where you might want a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs `Y` can't be a reference type here, because we're converting a pointer (the results of a `new` expression).  `dynamic_cast` can convert pointers to pointers, or references to references, but not pointers to references or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely unanswerable without knowing Y and X. For example, if Y is int, then illegal. Else, if Y is a pointer to a polymorphic class, it might succeed, or it might not, but there's certainly nothing "probable" about it. Finally, this is a rather nasty memory leak.