# Aws::Delete() attempting dynamic_cast on pointer to zero page

Tags: c++, aws-sdk, unreal-engine4, dynamic-cast

I am using the AWS SDK for C++ to access S3 buckets. This is as part of a larger Unreal Engine project. As such, the AWS SDK is using the Unreal Engine allocators, hooked in via `Aws::Utils::Memory::MemorySystemInterface`. When one of my requests goes out of scope (and is destroyed), I get a segmentation fault in `Aws::Delete()`. This only occurs for a specific `GetObject` request where i've specified a stream type for the request.

The code for the request that breaks is below:

```cpp
Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest request;
request.SetBucket(bucket);
request.SetKey(filename);
request.SetResponseStreamFactory([destination_file]() 
{return Aws::New<Aws::FStream>("getdata", destination_file, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary); }); 
//^ suspect this line to be causing problems, somehow.

Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome outcome = s3.GetObject(request);
if (!outcome.IsSuccess())
{
    Completed.Broadcast(fullpath, false);
    return;
}
else 
{
    fullpath = to_file;
    Completed.Broadcast(fullpath, true);
    return;
}
//request and outcome leave scope here, triggering an exception.
```

The request does complete successfully (`outcome.IsSuccess()` is `true`) and the file appears in the correct place. Once either `outcome` or `request` (i'm not sure which) leaves scope is where it crashes:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA0CC2612A (vcruntime140.dll) in UnrealEditor.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000068.
```

with the following call stack:

```
    vcruntime140.dll!00007ffa0cc2612a() Unknown
    [Inline Frame] aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!Aws::Delete(std::basic_iostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> * pointerToT) Line 117 C++
    aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!Aws::Utils::Stream::ResponseStream::ReleaseStream() Line 62    C++
    aws-cpp-sdk-core.dll!Aws::Utils::Stream::ResponseStream::~ResponseStream() Line 54  C++
    UnrealEditor-Plugin.dll!UPlugin::Activate() Line 56 C++
```

Specifically, the exception is triggered here in `AwsMemory.h`:

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type Delete(T* pointerToT)
    {
        if (pointerToT == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }
        // deal with deleting objects that implement multiple interfaces
        // see casting to pointer to void in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123776/are-there-practical-uses-for-dynamic-casting-to-void-pointer
        // NOTE: on some compilers, calling the destructor before doing the dynamic_cast affects how calculation of
        // the address of the most derived class.
        void* mostDerivedT = dynamic_cast<void*>(pointerToT); // <-- exception
        pointerToT->~T();
        Free(mostDerivedT);
    }
```

`ReleaseStream()` and `ResponseStream()` seem to just be wrappers for `Aws::Delete` for this particular instance, the only thing of note being that `ReleaseStream` flushes the stream before calling `Delete`. There's nothing that suggests `pointerToT` should be invalidated before the `dynamic_cast`, and yet it is. This *should* all be occurring on a single thread. I have also verified that all the relevant locals (like `destination_file`) are valid.

What could be causing this behaviour? This project has done other requests (List, Put & Get) without issue, although none of them have specified a stream factory.

Comment: We probably need a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UE4 is compiled without RTTI, so (obviously) `dynamic_cast` does not work. I believe this was the issue. There is a new problem with calling `Delete` on polymorphic types without using the `dynamic_cast<void*>` trick.